# Jmeter extracting JSON format inside an Array

Tags: arrays, json, api, jmeter, jsonpath

I would like to seek an assistance how can I extract the value USDT on this sample response. Your response is highly appreciated. Currently this is how I extract my USDT using JSON Path tester $..currency[0]. I want to make it flexible without using number instead contains. is there's a way to simulate this? Thank you so much in advance

```
{
    "uid": "123-321",
    "period": "25_minutes",
    "level": "symbol",
    "values": [
        1.3211,
        1.2212
    ],
    "rank_by": "volume",
    "currency": [
        "USDT",
        "SGD"
    ],
    "measurements": [
        0.42,
        0.15
    ],
    "num_instruments": 20,
    "asset_classes": [
        "All"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "timestamp": "2022-05-30T03:53:09"
}
```

Sample response I extracted:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `jsonpath-expression` to check if the value exists in the array

```
$..currency[?(@ == "USDT")]
```

[image: jsonpath.com]

Answer (score 2):

If you're uncertain about the order of currencies in the response you can consider

1. Switching to [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/)
2. [Sorting](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#sort) the array alphabetically
3. [Slicing](https://jmespath.org/proposals/array-slices.html) the array to return only last match (`USDT` will be "lower" than `SGD`)

[image]

Comment: nice dimtri, but what if YUN will be there ?

Answer (score 1):

Dont have clue about JSON extractor, but can be done through the following method,

1. Add JSR223 Postprocessor as a child of the request which returns
   above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

Script Block:

```
 def jsonResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
    jsonResponse.each { getCurrencyArray ->
            def currencyExpected = "USDT"
              if(getCurrencyArray.getKey() == "currency"){
                        getCurrencyArray.getValue().each { curr ->
                            if (curr.equalsIgnoreCase("USDT")) {
                                vars.put("Cur", currencyExpected )
                                log.info("Cur = " + currencyExpected)
                            }
                        }
              }
    }
```

With USDT:

[image]

With Multiple USDT:
[image]

Without USDT:
[image]